Was the single-level store (SLS) really a breakthrough?
I am reading Pugh's book on IBM, specifically the section on Future Systems (FS).
There were two key concepts in FS: high-level language support (HLS), and a single-level store (SLS). Both were intended to dramatically reduce the workload of writing programs, thereby making their machines more competitive at a higher price point (by saving on development costs).
I'm curious about SLS. At first glance I can see why this would be attractive: every program gains a persistence layer and the code needed to support it is minimal. You do a malloc and after that, you can refer to that memory even after a restart. But when I read about accounts of the System/38 and AS/400, it seems no one ever talks about it.
For the i-people out there, was this something as revolutionary as they believed it would be in the early 1970s? And how did you avoid writing all that file code anyway if you ended up talking to some other system, which I assume was a common use-case?

Eternal memory leaks? ツ

I suspect this was only really a good idea when memory and CPUs were pretty slow.  Also the cost of IBM could pay for a LOT of workload writing programs once there were high level languages, or even C, which probably affected the value proposition.

Perhaps, it could be better classified as a cute, but purely theoretical idea, which utter impracticality was realized as soon as an attempt at an implementation was made.

There has been many version of this even relatively recently. HPE tried to build a all-DRAM machine with 100+TB of memory that eliminates the need of hard drives. And NV-DIMM and Optane that tried to replace DRAM with byte-addressable persistent flash. IMO all of these seems incomplete because there are much more volatile states in a computer than just DRAM or storage, e.g. CPU registers, page tables, cache, and very importantly, time. The Unix mmap is already the best we can do with unified internal-external storage.

It's basically virtual memory, which was revolutionary, and mmap is still alive and kicking in current Linux, and yes, it's a lot simpler to just mmap the file and have done with it (easy C exercise for yourself if you want to compare code). I guess the only difference is that the idea to associate it with a permanent address or an object identifier as in Multics never caught on, instead you still associate it with a file as the identifier.

@dirkt Segments in Multics didn't have persistent addresses from process to process. Each segment had a pathname in the file system.

My interpretation of the question is: was SLS a programmer-visible feature, and if so, how much was it used in actual System 38 / AS-400-based systems?

Back in 1980s and early 1990s, IBM talked about Single Level Storage a lot.  I remember hearing Frank Soltis (one of the original architects) talk about it many times.  This was the era when the S/38 and AS/400 were proud to be different from Unix.
Frank dreamt of a day when large, persistent, solid state storage would be cheap enough to replace disk drives.  However, although we now have storage that he could not even dream of, there is still a distinction between (comparatively) small, fast, and non-persistent storage and large, slow, persistent storage.
Since the AS/400 (or its descendants) began to embrace rather than shun Unix, things started to change.  Now we have an option for "TeraSpace" on compiles.  This is touted as an advanced feature but really it is turning off single level storage.   Today, you are right, IBM don't talk about Single Level Storage often.
It was always very well hidden from the programmer.  RPG (1) and Cobol were quite traditional and had typical files and arrays.  Maybe files were not always on disk and arrays not always in memory but the programmer would not know.  Few cared about the subject and wrote their programs just as they would on any other system.  I remember one case when a programmer tried to solve a performance problem by reading a whole file into an array.  He was disappointed that it got slower rather than faster.  I said that I was not surprised and reminded (told) him about Single Level Storage.
(1) An ugly language but popular on the S/38 and AS/400.  It looks very different from Cobol but the power is similar.
